# Using cost path in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I'm new to using the Least Cost Path tool.

I have a depth raster (tiff format) and I would like to calculate the cost path between two points close to the land. I need to "force" the tool to calculate the path below 25 m and I do not know how to do that.

I have attached a pic where I show the cost path but I want it close to the coast.

Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Only to understand the problem. The Costpath should not touch land and be between -25m to 0 depth in the water?

Comment: the way i understand it, it cant touch land and it has to be a greater depth than 25m (most likely the boats draft)

Comment: Hi EikeMike and ed.hank, thanks for answer me. you are right, I would like to find a way that the costapth do not touch the land but be in that range (0-25 m depth).thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

To exclude higher depth than 25 m, you need to exclude the data from the raster. E.g. set the depth higher than 25 m to NULL using the raster calculator.

You should copy your raster first.